# Activerecord, order by field with a start ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to create a particular query.

I have db with some magazines and in my views I'm creating a coverflow of the last 20 magazines. When I show a record I want to start the coverflow from that particular record, keeping the default order.

My model is this:

```
class Magazine < ActiveRecord::Base
 default_scope lambda { order 'number DESC' }
 scope :published, -> { where(visible: true).where 'published_at <= ?', Time.zone.now }
end
```

and my controller for the "show" action is

```
def show
    #add scope to magazine.all
    @magazine = Magazine.published.find(params[:id])
    @magazines = Magazine.published.limit(20)
    if @magazine.can_show?
      render :show
    else
      not_found
    end
  end
```

@magazine is ordered by number DESC, but I need to introduce an offset where the starting ID is the @magazine.id.

Detailed example

NOW @magazine is this:

```
@magazines = [20,19,18,17,16,14,13,12,11,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
@magazine.id = 7
```

I want a way to use @magazine.id as starting point. The result must be:

```
@magazines = [7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
```

With @magazine = 14 the result must be

```
 @magazines = [14,13,12,11,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
```

Is there any command to create a scope like this?

Comment: Please explain it in details

Comment: edited, but I think is detailed

Comment: in which order magazines are stored in database?

Comment: check my answer, looks like thats what you want

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve with single line:

```
@magazines.drop(@magazines.index(@magazine.id)) if @magazines.include?(@magazine.id)
```

Example:

```
> @magazines
 => [20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 14, 13, 12, 11, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
> @magazines.drop(@magazines.index(14))
 => [14, 13, 12, 11, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
> @magazines.drop(@magazines.index(7))
 => [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: mmh... you are right! I need to search starting from magazine.id so every @magazine return me always the last 20 magazines starting from the selected.

Answer (score 0):

One liner, other method to it

```
@magazines = @magazines.slice(@magazines.index(@magazine.id), @magazines.size) if @magazines.include?(@magazine.id)
```

Comment: `[7,20,19,18,17,16,14,13,12,11,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]` does not match with OP output - `[7,6,5,4,3,2,1,20,19,18,17,16,14,13,12,11,9,8]`

Comment: He said this "I want a way to shift the array without changing the order but using the @magazine.id as starting point."